# Link XIB to a custom NSView in a Framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am writing a Cocoa Framework (not an Application), it contains the definition of a customized `NSView`; the framework will be loaded in other applications, and the customized `NSView` will be dragged to the GUI of the applications and become initialized

The question is that I want to include a XIB file in the Framework

I want to add a button and a label to the XIB (in the framework), but the view in the application that consumes the framework, won't show the button and the label

I already set the File's Owner of XIB to the custom `NSView` in the framework

What else should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Have the view load the nib and move the button, label, etc., from the view in the nib to itself.

It'll be easiest to do this just by getting the `subviews` of the nib's view and doing this for all of them.

If your nib uses Auto Layout, I *think* you'll also need to bring across any constraints owned by the nib's view, and you may also need to edit or replace any constraints that refer to that view (e.g., if a view is set to be X points away from an edge of the nib's view).

You may also need to do extra work to change the new view's frame, or to change the frames of the subviews (whether by relocation, resizing, or both) to match the frame given for the new view.

Comment: Thanks you are right, I just solved the issue, strategy is almost the same, I will come up with more details

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I just solved the issue, and I hope the details are helpful to others.

In the framework, there is a complicated subclass of `NSView`, which contains many controls such as `NSSplitView` `NSOutlineView` and `IKImageBrowserView`, `NSPathControl` and etc; the framework contains a H file, a M file and a XIB file; H and M define the `MyView` class; in the XIB, there is a View object whose class is `MyView`.

On the application side, users need to drag a `NSView` item onto the main window of their app, and assign an outlet to the view, let's say `mainView`, and in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` function of the "consumer" app, the follow code is necessary

```
NSBundle *frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[MyView class]];

NSNib *nibby = [[[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"MyView" bundle:frameworkBundle] autorelease];

NSArray *topLevelObjects = nil;

BOOL flag = [nibby instantiateNibWithOwner:nil topLevelObjects:&topLevelObjects];

assert(flag);

for (id topLevelObject in topLevelObjects) {
    if ([topLevelObject isKindOfClass:[MyView class]]) {

        [mainView addSubview: topLevelObject];
        MyView* xView = topLevelObject;
        [xView setFrameSize:mainView.frame.size];
        break;
    }
}
```

In the code above, the XIB files is loaded, thus the `MyView` object is initialized, then we fetch it out of the XIB, resize it and add it to the main view of the window

Comment: There is no reason why every application should have to repeat all that boilerplate. The view class can do all of that itself within one of the initializer methods. (Also, are you sure that, where you have `initWithNibNamed:@"path/to/the/XIB" bundle:nil`, you don't mean `initWithNibNamed:@"nameOfTheNib" bundle:frameworkBundle`? The whole point of bundles is to not have to refer to everything by absolute paths.)

Comment: @PeterHosey You are right Peter, thanks for that. I have modified the part about loading Nib from framework bundle. Will you enlighten me about "loading nib with view's initializer"? with more details?

Comment: In your view class, you'd implement one of the `init` methods and load your nib and move your subviews over in there.